# pip is not recognized in Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I'm using Anaconda on Windows x64. I'm trying to install some library using pip. However, the the command line isn't recognizing pip or any other scripts. The folder that they are all in is in both the user and system PATH variable. pip is there and works if I use the entire file path. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does typing `python` do anything?

Comment: In the python command prompt no. In the anaconda command prompt, the output is "Python 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:32:42) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information."

Comment: What does typing `pip` in the anaconda command prompt do?

Comment: Returns "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: In the python command line prompt, type `import sys` then `sys.executable`

Comment: Then check is `pip.exe` in the installation `Scripts` directory.

Comment: pip.exe is in the Scripts directory. sys.executable returns "C:\\Anaconda3\\python.exe"

Comment: Is the `Scripts` directory on your `PATH`? You can see your PATH by running `path` at the command prompt.

Answer (score 15):

When creating your environment, you need to specify pip as a dependency:

```
conda create --name my-env pip
activate my-env
pip install ...
```

Installing a new environment with all default anaconda packages:

```
conda create --name my-env anaconda
```

Comment: Do you know how to install pip on Windows if one didn't specify pip as a dependency?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680946/how-to-add-package-to-conda-environment-without-pip
Note that its best not to gradually add packages to a conda environment though. Instead, add all dependencies to a conda environment and reinstall the environment from there. This helps to avoid package conflicts and ensures you have a shareable and reproducible environment.

Answer (score 15):

Do this worked for me:

```sh
conda install pip
```

and try:

```sh
pip install package_name
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have the following dir added to PATH:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

Comment: His Anaconda is installed in `C:\Anaconda3`, not `C:\Python27`.

Comment: I'm not sure how Anaconda is setup but I assume that there's some similarity to Python regarding the Scripts directory @asmeurer

Comment: This works to a point, but fails I think because an environment isn't setup with the packages pip needs to connect to Pypa. Using the Anaconda prompt and running pip install seems to be the easiest way to install packages in anaconda. I'm just starting to learn how to use anaconda and about environments.

Answer (score 2):

I worked for me if I start cmd and do cd C:\Users\ComputerName\Python27\Scripts
Then I typed in 'pip install "library"' and it worked!
If you don't know how to access cmd just press Win+R and type in cmd!

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Try typing

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

in CMD

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had it myself because of my username which uses this character "ï" which causes an encoding problem in the PATH variable. Therefore, scripts cannot be found by anaconda.
I had to install Anaconda **For everyone** and not just the current user to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add script folder location to path, for individual user installation it will be "`C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda3\Scripts"` and for everyone installation it can be found in Program Files "`C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts`"