# How to add package to conda environment without pip

Tags: anaconda, conda

How can I add a package to an existing conda environment?

If it is a python package I can use `pip install <package>`, but what if pip does not work?

Is it sufficient to activate the environment and use `conda install <package>`?

Comment: What if both `conda install` and `pip install` don't work?

Comment: For the opposite: [How to install packages in conda that are not available in anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57326043/7758804)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You've answered your own question. In fact you really want to do `conda install ...` instead of using pip if you can.

You can install a conda package also without activating the environment. Just use `conda install -n <env_name> <package>` or `conda install -p <path/to/env> <package>`.

Comment: Is it recommended to use `conda-forge`? (e.g. `conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow`)

Comment: @Joe Using `conda-forge` is just specifying the channel on Anaconda where the installer should look for the package. As long as the package you want is in the main/default channel (i.e. the one that's searched when you run `conda install` without the `-c` flag), I don't see any reason to use `conda-forge`

Answer (score 35):

If you want to install a specific package inside a specific conda environment, you can use the following command.

First activate the conda environment and then do:

```
$ conda install --name <conda_env_name> -c <channel_name> <package_name>
```

For a concrete example, let's assume that you want to install [chainer](http://chainer.org) from the *channel* `anaconda` to an already created conda environment named `chainerenv`, then you can do:

```
$ conda install --name chainerenv -c anaconda chainer
```

Comment: Why would one need to activate the conda environment if one is also including the `--name <env_name>` flag in one’s command to name the environment?

Comment: Inside a conda virtual environment, it is not necessary to use `-n` to specify the environment since we are already inside the environment.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install a package in the environment, you can use

```
conda install -p /path/to/env package
```

example:

```
conda install -p /users/dekstop/env-test Django
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative way to do this and I have just tested it on my own mac:

example: i want to install a non-conda package at my python2.7 environment:

1. go to terminal
2. activate the desired environment by: `source activate py27`
3. after you successfully activated the environment, you can install the package you wanted by: `pip install package`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes (usually). 
  One example is that you can activate your conda environment and then directly do `conda install pandas.tar.bz2` on the existing tar.bz2 files from `/conda_envs/.pkgs` (leftovers from **other environments**) 
If you don't have a tarball package like that but you have the src with **setup.py** you can just do the usual install by `python setup.py install` (or `python setup.py develop` to link the src)