# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api' in IDLE on import win32com

Tags: python, winapi, anaconda, win32com

When using Spyder, everything works without problem.

I does not though in a virtual environment out of anaconda.

I created a **virtual environment** and installed pywin32 with pip.
I created a simple test script in Idle with just 1 line: **import win32com** . 
It causes the error.

I checked the versions: all 64 bit. 
I use **python version 3.7.4** and **pywin32 version 225**.

I ran the post install procedure, to no avail. 
To be sure I had the latest version of pywin32, I downloaded it from github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases. 
I uninstalled Python and reinstalled it.

I have no solution in sight and no more inspiration.

Comment: To install a specific package such as SciPy into an existing environment "myenv":

`conda install --name myenv scipy` from [Installing Packages](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-packages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add package to conda environment without pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680946/how-to-add-package-to-conda-environment-without-pip)

Comment: Check the [`sys.path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897792/where-is-pythons-sys-path-initialized-from) to make sure you install win32api for the python version you are using if there are multiple versions. And install `pypiwin32` instead of `pywin32` to see if it helps.