# How to install qt5ct window style in a conda venv

Tags: python, conda

I created a conda venv and installed spyder 3.3.6. When I run Spyder outside the venv I'm able to go to Tools > Preferences > General > Appearance > Interface and choose "qt5ct" in the "QT windows style" options. This isn't available when I run spyder from the conda venv for some reason. I double-checked my Linux Mint Synaptic Package Manager, and qt5ct package is indeed installed. But...

`conda install -n spyder-env qt5ct`

...[as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33698605) doesn't work, it returns:

```
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - qt5ct

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

[I don't think qt5ct is available](https://anaconda.org/search?q=qt5ct), so am I SOL?

Comment: If you already have Spyder installed outside Conda, why not continue to use that? One only requires a single Spyder instance and just needs to install `spyder-kernels` in the Conda environments you wish to use in Spyder as kernels. See [the documentation](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder).

Comment: I went through the steps for "The modular approach" in the documentation you linked, and Spyder returns "Invalid file path:" when I try to put in the path given by the command in step 3.

Comment: That's not enough info to help you. Maybe share the command. Or strike up a convo with someone on Gitter: https://gitter.im/spyder-ide/public

Comment: ```conda install -n spyder-env spyder-kernel```, to which it returned ```# All requested packages already installed```, then ```conda activate spyder-env``` and ```python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"```, which returned ```/home/user/miniconda3/envs/spyder-env/bin/python```. I put that into Spyder>Tools>Preferences>Python Interpreter>Use the following Python interpreter:, and it returned "Invalid file path:" in a popup.

Comment: Frak, now it's working. Kudos to merv on that documentation link. "Invalid file path:" isn't popping up when I tried it after grabbing some food, regardless of if spyder-env is active or not. Also appears to be persistent when I restart Spyder itself. Maybe something needed time to restart or propagate? I dunno. Great Success.