# PIP command for Django Installation

Tags: python, django, pip

I have installed python using Anaconda platform, The problem is that when I want to install Django through command prompt, it shows an error 'pip is not recognized as an internal or external command.'
Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you find answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055393/pip-is-not-recognized-in-anaconda-prompt)?

Comment: Yes, Scroll Down for the Answers.

Comment: Yes, Scroll Down for the Answers.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, In anaconda platform you can't use `pip`, you have to use `conda`.
And to install django in anaconda platform, try running the following command, `conda install django`.

Or try this url https://www.coresumo.com/install-django-on-anaconda/

you can also try `conda install pip` and then continue as normal python environment after creating the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

try `conda create --name myenv`
and then activate the environment using `myenv\source\activate` and then install pip using 
`conda install pip` after that you can install django.
[follow this link after the process for better understanding](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/installation/#pythonanywhere) and there also guide lines to install Django in the newly created virtual environment.

Comment: The issue is accessing pip. Even using a virtual environment wouldn't help if python isn't added to the system path.

Comment: I think that can be accessed through virtual environment created using `conda create --name my-env pip` and then he should be able access pip, since it creates a whole new environment, if he is not able to create virtual environment then it might be the path variable issue of windows.

Comment: But it also shows that conda is not a recognized as internal or external command.

Comment: Then it might be path variable issue of windows

Comment: try adding in system environment variable, add path `c\users\prasun\anaconda3\scripts`

Answer (score 0):

Just do these steps:-

1) create a virtual environment and activate the same virtual environment.

2) then install Django with pip.

If you are using Ubuntu then run below command on terminal.

```
$ mkvirtualenv <virtual_env_name> or virtualenv <virtual_env_name>
$ workon <virtual_env_name> or source <virtual_env_name>/bin/activate
$ conda install pip
$ conda install django or pip install django
```

for window user refer http://www.learnexia.com/?p=857 and https://anaconda.org/anaconda/django